# Insert new or update version - sqlite (android)

Tags: sqlite, insert-update

I need to insert new record if it doesn't exist OR update a column (version no) by incrementing the current value it if exists already.

```
create table t(id int, version int);
```

I'm trying to get this done using a single SQL statement but I can't seem to find a suitable control flow statement. Would appreciate any help on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well seems to me that you need a few lines. 
Take input from user check if it exists, iF the returned cursor(for android, there must be some return value for other) is null put an insert statement if cursor is not null then update the returned cursor position with the new value

Like first perform `select * from tablename where title = ""`
Now if the returned value is null

```
insert into ....
```

If not

```
update table tablename ----
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I'm already using similar approach & I'm looking for a way to get around having to make multiple DB queries.

Comment: afaik: There's no practical way to implement 'createOrUpdate' without using two SQL statements.